# How to automatically deploy a new resource from Azure Automation to DSC nodes?

Tags: azure, dsc

Scenario:

1. I have a Windows 10 workstation on-boarded to Azure Automation (AA). It is configured to pull configuration from AA correctly - checked.
2. I wish to install Sql Server 2016 Developer edition on that workstation.
3. I imported the SqlServerDsc resource into my AA account from its NuGet page ([SqlServerDsc 11.1.0.0 | powershellgallery.com](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServerDsc/11.1.0.0)) by clicking the Deploy to Azure Automation button

Now I am wondering how that resource ends up installed on my DSC node. Surely I can install it manually, but I do not want to. I want it to be deployed there automatically. And in general, I do not want to install my resources manually - I want them to be deployed automatically.

I cannot find what do I need to configure to make it happen. Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your machine needs to be configured to use the Azure Automation server as it's pull server for DSC, you can follow [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-dsc-onboarding) for details on how to do it.

Once it is onboarded into your account you should then be able to assign the configuration you created to it using the Azure portal and the configuration should be applied.

Comment: Hi Sam. I know all that, the machine is already configured and is pulling configuration. BUT, it does not have all the resources I want to use out of the box. For example, the SqlServerDsc resource is missing by default. Now how do I deliver the resource to that machine? I do not want to install it manually.

Comment: You don't need to install them, the DSC Automation server knows you require these resources at compile time (because you specify them in the import-dscresource commands) and they are available on the pull server. When a configuration is applied to a node any required resources are also supplied.

Comment: I feel so stupid for not realizing it.So, if I imported the resource to my Azure Account then it is ready to use on machines that do not have it initially, right?

Comment: Yep, that's correct